# Bootstrap : how to move label to the right of the input in form-horizontal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Well, I'm trying to set label on the right of the input using Bootstrap but I can't manage it.
I searched at internet and tried several pieces of code but nothing works...

In this [link](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) the label is on the right but I don't know how to do it.

[Fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/nhogLn6e/)

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Align Label Form</legend>

<div class="col-sm-6"><!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Left Align</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6"><!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Right Align</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just put your label after your input. Like:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
</div>
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="textinput">Right Align</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

[**Something like this ?**](https://jsfiddle.net/885b4tcv/). simply put your label after the input, and align it to the left.

```
// Mandatory plunkr code
```

Answer (score 1):

## **Solution**

I've edited your code so it shows the labels and inputs inline: **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyler_crawford/hub95r7w/)**.

## **Explanation**

**1. Use the Bootstrap Grid to Your Advantage!**

The first issue I see with your markup is that your sibling nodes' (Input Div and Label) classes do not add up to 12. In Bootstrap, all related html nodes (tags) must add up to **12** if you would like them to equally fill the Bootstrap grid.

In the Fiddle, you will see that I edited your Label and Input Div to match this rule (4 + 8 = 12):

```
<!-- Text input-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Left Align</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
      <input id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**2. Col Class Types Matter!**

You'll see that in my HTML, I have different usages of `col-*-#` classes. These determine the column grid breakpoints for the size of your viewport. Example: `col-xs-12`. You can think of the class structure as: `column - viewport size (xs = extra small) - how many columns to take up (12 columns)`.

**[Here's](https://tutorialzine.com/media/2017/01/1-basic-grid.png)** a simple but great visual for seeing the different column spans you can produce.

You were most likely looking at your JS Fiddle Results window as a small box in the bottom right corner. Because it is such a small viewport, you need to use a class that matches it's resolution range: `col-**xs**-#`. The **xs** denotes the smallest device range in the Bootstrap grid layout.

You can add multiple col classes to handle shrinking / expanding viewports. In my Fiddle, try expanding and shrinking the Results box. You'll see that it tries to keep the Input and Label inline, even if that means the elements themselves start looking weird.

If you removed col-sm-4 / col-sm-8 from an Input / Label pairing, you'll see a drastic break of format when expanding from a small Result box.

## **References**

**1. Tutorial**

There's a ton of tutorials out there, but I like **[Derek Banas's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqOEoUR5RHg)** straightforward delivery.

**2. Bootstrap Docs**

Go to the source! **[Here's](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)** some of Bootstrap's own documentation on their Grid System. *Note: the link provided is for Bootstrap 4, but the basic Grid classes for what we are discussing has not changed much.